# Material Theme UI - annoying dark lines

Tags: intellij-idea

Silly question, but, does anyone know how to change the colour of these dark separator lines in intellij?

I'm using material theme UI plugin but can't seem to find this in the settings or in the colour scheme.

Thanks

[image]

Comment: https://github.com/ChrisRM/material-theme-jetbrains/issues ?

Comment: There are many IntelliJ **code** themes with all sorts of custom coloring, but I've never heard of a **general UI** theme other than built in regular and darcula theme

Answer (score 0, accepted):

menu  :Tools -> Vim Emulator       close